# I have a small piece of stainless steel that I need to remove 1-2mm of material. The hardness is 200. What type of file do I need to get?

Tags: steel, metallurgy, machining, material-science

This is a part of a mounting system for an Olight pistol flashlight.  The universal adapter that they include isn't so universal when it comes to a Canik handgun.  I've talked to the people at Olight and their engineers say its made of stainless steel with a hardness of 200.  I need to remove 1-2 mm of material off the adapter for a proper fit but I don't know what type of file I need.  I think I can accomplish this with a hand file and time with the proper tool.  I know that some metals are softer than others, thats why I'm asking.  I don't want to purchase a file that won't scratch this hardness but it works wonders on gold/silver or aluminium.  I also have a dremel rotary tool if you think that might work better than a hand file.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: Take it to a macine shop so it is machined flat and square.

Answer (score 1):

Removing 1 or 2 mm of stainless would require a grinder unless you want to spend many hours with a file. Or ,as commented, take it to a machine shop. Stainless would not be expected to be hard. "200" looks like Brinell or Vickers hardness ,could be cold rolled 304, still not much compared to the 600 Vickers or Brinell of an ordinary file.

Comment: The steel has a dark brown color to it.  I always thought stainless steel was gray/silver like kitchen equipment.  I have screwdriver sets that are similar in this brownish color and I think they are considered tool steel, but I'm comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Hot rolled it is black to dark brown. Once had many millions of refinery equipment delivered. About 1/2 thick hot rolled  304 , we had to convince the manager every thing was good. It was going to operate at 1200 + F so it  would turn black in service so no reason to make it polished silver. Sheet metal I would expect to be silver colored when new.